# How do i save my CSV file to a location for the user to select?

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

Hi i have searched for this codes that create a csv file but this only works by indicating a default location. How should i do if i would like to define the file location?

```
    private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Build the CSV file data as a Comma separated string.
    string csv = string.Empty;

    //Add the Header row for CSV file.
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        csv += column.HeaderText + ',';
    }

    //Add new line.
    csv += "\r\n";

    //Adding the Rows
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            //Add the Data rows.
            csv += cell.Value.ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
        }

        //Add new line.
        csv += "\r\n";
    }

    //Exporting to CSV.
    string folderPath = "C:\\CSV\\";
    File.WriteAllText(folderPath + "DataGridViewExport.csv", csv);
}
```

Comment: Use a SaveFileDialog

Comment: Sidenote: Don't do this on the GUI-Thread ... Your application might become unresponsive on large data sets.

Comment: reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
string selectedPath = "";
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    selectedPath = dialog.FileName;
}
```

You can select options like the start directory etc, but overall it's pretty easy to use.

Comment: Hi how do i customise the file type and the saving file name in the saveFileDialog?

Comment: Use the filter property like this dialog.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";